# Other unique data than SECURE_ID on Android and IDFV on iOS (latest API lvls)?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Is there any unique data that can we can get instead of:

- SECURE_ID on Android
- IDFV on iOS

I know that latest OS changes do not allow to get non-resettable data like Serial Number, MAC addresses and so on.
But is there anything else that is unique for the device and can be used? How do you handle a situation that SECURE_ID/IDFV is not enough?

Comment: You haven't explained why IDFV is "not enough" but you on iOS have the option of storing your own unique identifier in the keychain. This will survive app reinstallation but not device erasure and storing two bits of data with the DeviceCheck framework. The values of these two bits will survive a complete device reset